# Is there a better/easier way to update a json file in Java?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Say, I have a json file like below:

```
[{
  "obj1_key1":"aa",
  "obj1_array":[{"e1":"11"},{"e2":"22"}]
},
{
  "obj2_key1":"cc",
  "obj2_key2":"dd"
}]
```

Now I want update the file into something like below:

```
[{
  "obj1_key1":"aa",
  "obj1_array":[{"e1":"11"},{"e2":"22"},{"e3":"333"}]
},
{
  "obj2_key1":"cc",
  "obj2_key2":"dd"
}]
```

I tried using `ObjectMapper` to parse the file like

```
JsonNode jsonFile = new ObjectMapper().readTree(new File("file.json");
```

however then I need to find the `obj1_array` and append a json object, then write the json object back to the file. And I don't think the way I load the json file as a `JsonNode` is a easy way because I should convert it between Json/JsonArray back and forth. So I'm wondering is there a simpler way to make this work? Really appreciate that.

Comment: Reading, looking up, modifying and writing back is the simplest way to update a file. You could write a DAO to hide these details if you want to simplify it for the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

if it is just a one-off case, you can use your preferred mechanism, but if it is going to used often, I would prefer

1. Convert the JSON to a POJO ( using some parser eg Jackson )
2. Update the requisite fields
3. Return the Json object.